# Data at rest encryption for remote unattended Ubuntu & PostgreSQL machine

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, security, encryption

I'm looking for a data at rest solution for our setup.

Our application runs on our clients' machines, set up by their IT guys (however, they don't possess any credentials), and located on-premise. We log in via SSH. The machines are meant to stay up. We're storing sensitive information and would need to encrypt it to meet data-at-rest requirements. We're using Ubuntu 18.04+ and PostgreSQL.

I've looked into different solutions and gathered some information from several related previously asked questions:

1. **Full disk encryption** - since their IT is not really available to us, going in that direction might be problematic, as it would require performing more steps on their side. Also, if (when) the server ever gets rebooted, we would need to log in via SSH to enter the passphrase or use some kind of network-bound encryption, which again requires additional set up and the additional resources might not even be available to us.
2. **File-based encryption** - use something like eCryptfs and store the PostgreSQL data directory in an encrypted file system. This is currently the only solution I found that solves most of the issues; however, there might be other directories that would need encryption, and I'm not certain if they can be encrypted in that method (like `/tmp`). Once rebooted, the file system wouldn't be mounted automatically, and we would need to mount it manually. I don't see how we can solve this without, again, network-bound encryption. eCryptfs also let the user enter whatever configurations and passphrase they want upon every mounting, even if they don't match the previously used settings, which I think is prone to files getting corrupted. Writing a program that intercepts the mounting and validates the passphrase might be a possible solution to this. Handling problems like hanging processes when the FS isn't mounted is also okay for now, but overall this solution doesn't scale nicely.
3. **Column-based encryption, client-side encryption, etc** - doesn't work for our setup. We want to be able to query the data over SSH. The client is stored on the same machine with the data. Using something like PGP keys would mean the data is effectively unencrypted.
4. We don't use cloud services of sorts.

Maybe we need a different setup, or there are other solutions I'm not aware of. I'm *really* new to this subject and in the Stack Overflow community. The solutions I've found over the internet seem sparse and dated, and I'm not sure they're still relevant.